# NextJS, Redux-tk Chrome Devtools Showing Incorrect Values on Breakpoint

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, gulp, google-chrome-devtools

Thanks for your attention.

i've set up a new application (next, react, redux-tk, gulp), and everything is working swimmingly in both local and hosted on the server. **but i just cant seem to get the devtools working correctly.** when i pause the debugger, values are all over the place and incorrect under the Sources tab -> hover over var/under Scope section. i think the sourcemaps are configured alright but im also not sure. here's the set-up which i've learned are supposed to connect things properly:

- I have the redux-devtools-extension installed (is even necessary w/ rtk?)
- Using the new rtk configureStore in *store.js*, which should enable devtools automatically from what i understand, but i've got a prod condition there:

```
    export const store = configureStore({
        reducer: {
            // reducers removed for brevity
        },
        devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'prod'
    });
```

- my *next.config.js* has *productionBrowserSourceMaps* set to true:

```
    module.exports = {
        env: {
            environment: env
        },
        productionBrowserSourceMaps: true,
        basePath: basePath
    };
```

- Chrome Devtools' sourcemaps setting is set to true.
- My *gulpfile.js* has **no** related source maps/compiling config, just using it for sass processing.
- Am i missing something? Babel perhaps? Not much experience there.

[image: devtools issue]
here's an example. when i pause here, selectedShip is definitely a ship object as i see it in the console and how it operates in the app (with name, shipCode, etc.), but in devtools its showing as the router object. not to mention there's two pcl-global-headers elements apparently being tracked. when there definitely isnt. this makes debugging basically impossible using sources lol. any ideas? am i missing something silly and small? please tell me im missing something silly and small

thanks again! hope you're having a great day!